# Duda crear sublistas con strings

Tags: python

que tal? he estado teniendo conflictos con un ejercicio :

Se ingresan padron y notas de 200 alumnos aleatoriamente, ordenarlas de mayor a menor por padron

Lo que me estaba causando algunos problemas es, como puedo agregar una sublista a otra lista? debo usar el metodo extend? les dejo como progrese con el programa ( ordenarlos no me resulta dificil ya que solo uso lista.sort(reverse=True).

```
 
 def iniciar_matriz ():
     matriz = []   #padron filas alumnos columnas
 
         
     for i in range(3):
         while True:
             legajo = int(input("ingrese el legajo(fin=00):\n"))
             alumno = input("ingrese el alumno:\n")
             matriz.extend([legajo,alumno])
             if legajo==00 :
                 break
             
             
                 
 
     return matriz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que uses `append` y no `extend`:

```
def iniciar_matriz ():
     matriz = []   #padron filas alumnos columnas
 
         
     for i in range(3):
         while True:
             legajo = int(input("ingrese el legajo(fin=00):\n"))
             alumno = input("ingrese el alumno:\n")
             matriz.append([legajo,alumno])
             if legajo==00 :
                 break
             
             
                 
 
     return matriz
```

Razón: Con `extend` estás añadiendo los valores al array así:

```
[5, "alumno1", 6, "alumno2"] # esto es un solo array con TODOS los valores en línea
```

Con `append`:

```
[[5, "alumno1"], [6, "alumno2"]]  # Esto es un array con múltiples arrays dentro
 # hace más fácil que puedas recorrerlo alumno a alumno luego
```

Puedes ver más información [aquí](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/append-extend-python/)